# Function not returning result in c (in a project file)

Tags: c, dev-c++

When I run this code in a .c file, it works, but when I make a project for it, the function I call will only return 0.00. Why? Why does it not work in a project file?

I'm using DevC++.

```
#include<stdio.h>

float mean(int total, int max);

int main(){
    int i,max, total=0;
    int array[max];
    printf("Enter max: ");
    scanf("%d",&max);

    for(i=0; i<max; i++){
        scanf("%d",&array[i]);
        total+=array[i];
    }
    printf("Total: %d\n",total);
    printf("Mean: %.2f",mean(total,max));
    return 0;
}

float mean(int total, int max){
    float ave;
    ave=(float)total/max;

    return ave;
}
```

Comment: The code you show should not even *build*. Please copy-paste the *actual* code you have. And if this is it, then you need to fix the build errors first.

Comment: Then consider this: What is the value of `max` *before* you initialize it with the call to `scanf`? What will the size of `array` be?

Comment: there was nothing wrong with the max and array. my problem was when i call mean(total,max); the output should be the ave, but it only shows 0.00 which is idk why

Comment: Oh so you like living on the edge and having ***undefined behavior***? Because that is what you have! When you use `max` to define the array `array` the value of `max` is *indeterminate*, and you will have undefined behavior. Having undefined behavior in your program means the whole program is *ill formed* and invalid. Nothing the program does can be trusted.

Comment: there was a ")" missing i agree..but my problem was when i call the unction to return something in a project file, it just doesnt return the right value..keeps returning 0.00 but when the code is in a single (.c) file, the function returns right.

Comment: is that possible? i only heard it here that a declaration is not above any other.. so can i do it?

Comment: how can i actually input the max first before declaring the array ?

Comment: @PatrickEsguerra, yes, declarations can follow executable statements in C since C99.  Even before C99 was published, some compilers accepted such ordering as an extension.

Comment: @DavidBowling: "*... declares int array[0].*" not necessarily. `max` had not been given a value yet, so using `max` already invokes the infamous Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: i did     int main(){
    int i,max, total=0;
    printf("Enter max: ");
    scanf("%d",&max);
    int array[max];   but mean is still 0.00

Comment: @alk-- Oh for crying out loud! I can't believe I misread that.... Thanks for the comment.

Comment: i did input for max first and declares the array but still mean is 0.00

Comment: @PatrickEsguerra if you've made that change and the above code still isn't working, then are you sure you've given us the code you're having problems with?

Comment: yes, if you got Devc++ there.. it should be in project

Answer (score 8):

The problem is with these two lines of code - you're declaring the size of `array` to be `max` before you actually work out what value `max` has which will cause unexplained behaviour. It's most likely pure chance that your code ever worked as expected.

```
int array[max];
...
scanf("%d",&max);
```

The way to do what you're trying to do is to allocate memory big enough to hold your array like this. You'd probably want to check that max is more than 0 too and also that `scanf` found a number. But the rough gist of it is like this:

```
int max;
int *array;
printf("Enter max: ");
scanf("%d",&max);
array=malloc(sizeof(int)*max);

/* your code goes here */

free(array);
```

Comment: there was nothing wrong with the max and array. my problem was when i call mean(total,max); the output should be the ave, but it only shows 0.00 which is idk why

Comment: @PatrickEsguerra - Everything is wrong with `max` and `array`. When seasoned programmers tell a novice they made a vital mistake, the novice better not just dismiss their claims.

Comment: @PatrickEsguerra: It is because of invoking undefined behaviour as explained per this answer.

Comment: @PatrickEsguerra just because you see the problem in one place, it doesn't mean the problem isn't caused by code elsewhere. In this particular instance, `max` could start off being 0 when you define `array`. Then you write into `array` you're going beyond the bounds of it which will corrupt your program's memory causing random errors.

Comment: i tried running it, theres nothing wrong with the max being the size of the array

Comment: can i initialize max first as 0? and then input for max and then use max as the size of the array?

Comment: @PatrickEsguerra no - see my above comment. you have to have a value for max before you declare your array. Or better yet, use `malloc` to allocate some memory based on the inputted value of `max` and use that

Comment: how do i go about it sir? how can i assign whatever max is to the array size?

Comment: can i do this?   int max=0, array[max] then printf("Max: "); scanf("%d",&max);   .. can the new max now replace the zero one?

Comment: I think [OP has it right here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43094087/function-not-returning-result-in-c/43094206#comment73270375_43094206). If `scanf()` is first used to set `max`, then `int array[max]` will work as desired, if he is using C99; `malloc()` may be needed if the compiler is older.

Comment: Or if it is newer @DavidBowling -- VLAs are an *optional* feature in C2011.  And considering that the OP is using dev-C++, it's worth noting that VLAs are not a feature of C++ at all.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include how to allocate (and later free) memory for your array

Comment: @John Bollinger-- I was avoiding comment on the C11 issue which seems an unlikely problem, but I hadn't considered the dev-C++ angle. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: i used your malloc code chris but mean is still 0.00

Comment: i did your updated code chris and the declaring of array before the input of max but still mean is 0.00

Comment: @PatrickEsguerra i've compiled the fixed code myself so I know it should work - maybe there is also a problem with how you're building the code?

Comment: what is the difference between a(.c) file and a project? .. it works in a single (.c) file but when i transfer it in a project it dont

Comment: ive done your int max;
int *array;
printf("Enter max: ");
scanf("%d",&max);
array=malloc(sizeof(int)*max);

/* your code goes here */

free(array);       but mean is still 0.00

Comment: a C file is just one file...a project is usually a collection of C and header files that are built together to form one program. But if you've just got the 1 C file in your project then there shouldn't really be any difference.

Comment: i really wonder whats wrong with my code that it returns 0.00 as the mean